# R: Barplot, add value directly next to bar and a description in a separate column

Tags: r, bar-chart

How can I achieve somethign like this in R:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this?

```
vec <- runif(5)
plot(0,0,type="n",xlim=c(0,1.5),ylim=c(0,7),bty="n",axes="off")
at<-barplot(vec,horiz=TRUE,add=TRUE)
text(vec,at,signif(vec,1),pos=4)
text(rep(1,5),at,c("mn","lu","co","-","my"))
```

Comment: Thx, that's exactly it!